# Run-time Error 1004 with Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create the below formula in Excel using VBA:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($F4,'17402'!$B:$BD,'17402'!AS$50,0))=TRUE,"",(VLOOKUP($F4,'17402'!$B:$BD,'17402'!AS$50,0)))
```

This is my code:

```
Dim wsFormula          As String
wsFormula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($F4," & "" '"" var_SN & ""'!"" & "$B:$BD," & ""'"" & var_SN & ""'!"" & "AS$50,0))=TRUE,0,(VLOOKUP($F4," & ""'"" var_SN & ""'!"" & "$B:$BD," & ""'"" var_SN & ""'!"" & "AS$50,0)))"
ActiveCell.Formula = wsFormula
```

Where “var_SN” is “17402”. I receive a Run-time error 1004, Application-defined or Object Define error error, so I wonder if the variable is the problem. I read about double stacking the quotes around ' and ! but that doesn't help.

I also wonder if the lookup value $F2 will become a problem for me as the row reference changes each time I run the macro. For instance, if I am in row 4, I do not want this code writing a formula that would reference cell F1 as the lookup value. Thanks much.

Comment: If you write the formula into several (or several thousand) rows at once then the `$F2` will automatically adjust the same way it would on a worksheet when you Fill Down. Alternately, change the formula to xlR1C1 style and it will be the same for all rows if you have to write them individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many "

Every where you have `17402` change to `" & var_SN & "`.

And the `""` Needs to be `""""`

```
"=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($F4,'" & var_SN & "'!$B:$BD,'" & var_SN & "'!AS$50,0))=TRUE,"""",(VLOOKUP($F4,'" & var_SN & "'!$B:$BD,'" & var_SN & "'!AS$50,0)))"
```

But you also do not need the `IF` and `ISERROR`.  You can use the `IFERROR`:

```
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F4,'" & var_SN & "'!$B:$BD,'" & var_SN & "'!AS$50,0),"""")"
```

The `IFERROR` will do the first argument unless there is an error then it does the second argument.

Comment: I changed the formula so that "$F4" will not always reference that cell, but always references the cell to the immediate left. I thought what I did below would work, but it doesn't. It looks similar to another relative reference formula I wrote, but this one sees RC1 as literally RC1. Here is the formula, please advise what I did wrong. Thanks.    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'" & var_SN & "'!$B:$BD,'" & var_SN & "'!AS$50,0),"""")"

Comment: @lindqmx1 If you are going to use r1c1 then all references must be in that format. in you case I would use `$F" & somevariableforrow & "` where obviously somevariableforrow is just that a variable that denotes the row on which the formulas is being placed.

Comment: @lindqmx1 or use the filldown method.  That will automatically change the references.

Comment: OK thanks. This is how I got it to work using your advice.    `var_SRN = ActiveCell.Row`
  `wsFormula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F" & var_SRN & ",'" & var_SN & "'!$B:$BD,'" & var_SN & "'!AS$50,0),"""")"`  

    `ActiveCell.Formula = wsFormula`

Comment: @lindqmx1 Glad I could help. please consider marking as correct.